# Scroll wheel rubber strip detachment

Tags: mouse, scrolling

The rubber friction strip on the scroll wheel of my Microsoft 4000 wireless mouse has broken free from the inner hard plastic hub. It has stretched to the point that I do not believe it could be re-attached and still work smoothly.  I am asking if a replacement wheel unit is available? I am also considering cutting the rubber ring, remove the stretched excess, and then gluing it back on the hub.  Thoughts? Alternate suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but in case anyone runs across this, just cut the rubber part off the wheel by lifting gently and cutting with a knife or nail clippers, mouse still works fine (it works optically not by friction)

Comment: It hurts my finger though!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the gooey rubber outer part of the wheel and then cleaning the exposed "rim" part of the wheel with some soft paper tissue works 100% fine; remove remaining debris from the top as well as the sides of the "rim" to let it run smooth again ... the mouse functions  100% fine...
(I actually took the mouse apart , but that is quite tricky and not necessary. I also used a bit of alcohol containing sanitizer on the soft tissue paper to help to remove the remaining glue and other rubber debris.)
Definitely NOT necessary to replace the mouse right away ! :-)